# Set together letters and numbers that are ordinal numbers

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

The purpose is to remove the space between the numbers and ordinal number abbreviation (st,rd,th,nd).

For instance, the following numbers and abbreviations should be together to form 10th, 1st and 133rd:

```
10   th elementary
1  st grade
133  rd anniversary
```

However, these other examples are not allowed to be set together:

```
abc123 th 33333    rddccc
10 thetree
20 street
```

For this purpose I have came out with the following regex:

```
(?<=[0-9])+\s+(?=(st|nd|rd|th)\b)
```

However it is setting together also the previous not allowed strings.

Do you know how can I set together just the correct ordinal numbers?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Green The OP's point is clear to me - they want to remove the spaces between numbers and their ordinal number abbreviations; i.e. match on `31  st ` but not `abcdefg238947 th`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might add another part to the positive lookahead to assert what follows is a word character except an underscore or digit or assert the end of the string in case it is the last occurrence:

```
(?<=[0-9])\s+(?=(?:st|[rn]d|th)(?: [^\W\d_]|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZTKVN/1)

Note that you can omit the `+` after the positive lookbehind and you might shorten the alternation to `[rn]d`

Comment: why you included `(?: [^\W\d_]|$)` as not capture group at second element in the positive lookahead? I see one case to avoid `10   th. elementary` why did you include `$` which cases would go there?

Comment: @JuanPerez I added it because you first want to check for `(?:st|[rn]d|th)` which could be followed by either a space and `[^\W\d_]` or the end of the string `$` In this case you don't have to capture it as it is not used for further processing.

Comment: I see what do you mean. Thanks a lot for your help @The fourth bird :)